# convert arm_compute::Image to cv::Mat

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, arm, computer-vision, neon

I have a lot of code that is based on open cv but there are many ways in which the Arm Compute library improves performance, so id like to integrate some arm compute library code into my project. Has anyone tried converting between the two corresponding Image structures? If so, what did you do? Or is there a way to share a pointer to the underlying data buffer without needing to copy image data and just set strides and flags appropriately?

Comment: Which specific functions do you think are better optimised in Arm Compute Library than OpenCV?

Comment: I am getting about 4x performance on creating image pyramids and 3x on harris corner detection, and maybe 20% improvement on optical flow. And this is a comparison between arm compute and NEON optimized opencv.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty impressive. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to configure an arm_compute::Image corresponding to my cv::Mat properties, allocate the memory, and point it to the data portion of my cv:Mat.

This way, I can process my image efficiently using arm_compute and maintain the opencv infrastructure I had for the rest of my project.

```
// cv::Mat mat defined and initialized above
arm_compute::Image image;

image.allocator()->init(arm_compute::TensorInfo(mat.cols, mat.rows, Format::U8));
image.allocator()->allocate();
image.allocator()->import_memory(Memory(mat.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for ACL 18.05 or newer**

You need to implement IMemoryRegion.h

I have created a gist for that: [link](https://gist.github.com/i7clock/246d6022fe78deda79a9b4473b7dc795)