# Arm Compute Library - Canny Edge returns unusable data from imported opencv image

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, neon

I am working with the arm compute library [link](https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary) to convert an opencv application to a more efficient code base.

I would like to import data from an opencv mat, which I've done successfully by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49200433/5981293).

```
arm_compute::Image matACL;
matACL.allocator()->init(arm_compute::TensorInfo(mat.cols, mat.rows, arm_compute::Format::U8)); // Initialise tensor's dimensions
matACL.allocator()->import_memory(arm_compute::Memory(mat.data)); //Allocate the image without any padding.

//matACL.allocator()->import_memory(arm_compute::Memory(new cvMatData(mat.data)));
```

Beware the versions 18.05 and above of the ACL need an implemented memory interface which I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/i7clock/246d6022fe78deda79a9b4473b7dc795) for. That's the commented line above.

I can run different operations on the image (threshold or gauss for example) and I can see the correct output in an opencv window, but whenever I use the canny edge detector I get a messed up output image. I have issued on [github](https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary/issues/474) a while ago, but they couldn't find a solution either.

I have implemented the canny edge neon like it is done in the NECannyEdge.cpp file to better understand what is happening. I copy the data of the result into an opencv Mat and preserve the pointer to it like that.

This is how I convert the result back to an OpenCV Mat:

```
ptr = (unsigned char*)malloc(mat.cols*mat.rows*sizeof(unsigned char));

for(unsigned int z = 0 ; z < 0 ; ++z)
{
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < mat.rows; ++y)
    {
        memcpy(ptr + z * (mat.cols * mat.rows) + y * mat.cols, matACL.buffer() +
        matACL.info()->offset_element_in_bytes(Coordinates(0, y, z)), mat.cols * 
        sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
}
```

and an alternative:

```
Window output_window;
output_window.use_tensor_dimensions(shape, Window::DimY);
Iterator output_it(&matACL, output_window);
execute_window_loop(output_window,
[&](const Coordinates & id)
{
    memcpy(ptr + id.z() * (mat.cols * mat.rows) + id.y() * mat.cols, output_it.ptr(), mat.cols * sizeof(unsigned char));
}, output_it);
```

The image sometimes showes a correct canny edge result but most of the time it shows random maybe unfinished data.

[image: Output Image]

I checked if it might be a race condition but the implementation should be single threaded and I can't figure out where the problem is. Does anyone have an idea?

How can I successfully use the data from an opencv image to use in the canny edge detector of the arm compute library? Maybe there is some steps during the import that I missed?

Thanks, Greetings

Comment: Please move essential parts of the github issues & code to your question for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Done @DmitriiZ. I hope this helps.

Comment: `The image sometimes showes a correct...` - This seems to me like a buffer stride issue but I'm not very familiar with ACL. One thing you can probably check is whether it works fine with 'even' images (512x512, 256x256 etc), and check what kind of stride does ACL image use

Comment: I got it to work @DmitriiZ. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where I was going wrong and developed this function, which creates an OpenCV Mat from an ACL Image:

```
void ACLImageToMat(arm_compute::Image &aCLImage, cv::Mat &cVImage, std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> &cVImageDataPtr)
{
    size_t width  = aCLImage.info()->valid_region().shape.x();
    size_t height = aCLImage.info()->valid_region().shape.y();

    cVImageDataPtr = std::make_unique < uint8_t[]>(width*height);
    auto ptr_src = aCLImage.buffer();


    arm_compute::Window input_window;
    input_window.use_tensor_dimensions(aCLImage.info()->tensor_shape());
    arm_compute::Iterator input_it(&aCLImage, input_window);
    int counter = 0;
    arm_compute::execute_window_loop(input_window,
        [&](const arm_compute::Coordinates & id)
        {
            *reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(cVImageDataPtr.get() + counter++) = ptr_src[aCLImage.info()->offset_element_in_bytes(id)];
        },
        input_it);


    cVImage = cv::Mat(cVImage.rows, cVImage.cols, CV_8UC1, cVImageDataPtr.get());
}
```

To initialize this for Canny I did the following:

```
    arm_compute::Image matACL;
    matACL.allocator()->init(arm_compute::TensorInfo(eye.cols, eye.rows, arm_compute::Format::U8));
    matACL.allocator()->import_memory(arm_compute::Memory(eye.data));

    arm_compute::Image matACLCanny;
    matACLCanny.allocator()->init(arm_compute::TensorInfo(eye.cols, eye.rows, arm_compute::Format::U8));

    arm_compute::NECannyEdge canny {};
    canny.configure(&matACL, &matACLCanny, 300, 150, 3, 1, arm_compute::BorderMode::REPLICATE);

    matACLCanny.allocator()->allocate();

    canny.run();
```

The IMPORTANT thing is to call the `allocate` function of the output image AFTER configuring the canny edge detector. I found this somewhere in the ACL documentation a while ago, but I can't remember where exactly.

I hope this helps someone who stumbles across converting images between the ACL and OpenCV!